# Huggingface Transformer - GPT2 resume training from saved checkpoint

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, language-model, gpt-2

Resuming the `GPT2` finetuning, implemented from `run_clm.py`

Does GPT2 [huggingface](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers)  has a parameter to resume the training from the saved checkpoint, instead training again from the beginning? Suppose the python notebook crashes while training, the checkpoints will be saved, but when I train the model again still it starts the training from the beginning.

Source: [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/examples/language-modeling/run_clm.py)

finetuning code:

```
!python3 run_clm.py \
    --train_file source.txt \
    --do_train \
    --output_dir gpt-finetuned \
    --overwrite_output_dir \
    --per_device_train_batch_size 2 \
    --model_name_or_path=gpt2 \
    --save_steps 100 \
    --num_train_epochs=1 \
    --block_size=200 \
    --tokenizer_name=gpt2
```

From the above code, `run_clm.py` is a script provided by [huggingface](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/examples/language-modeling/run_clm.py) to finetune gpt2 to train with the customized dataset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To resume training from checkpoint you use the `--model_name_or_path` parameter. So instead of giving the default `gpt2` you direct this to your latest checkpoint folder.

So your command becomes:

```
!python3 run_clm.py \
    --train_file source.txt \
    --do_train \
    --output_dir gpt-finetuned \
    --overwrite_output_dir \
    --per_device_train_batch_size 2 \
    --model_name_or_path=/content/models/checkpoint-5000 \
    --save_steps 100 \
    --num_train_epochs=1 \
    --block_size=200 \
    --tokenizer_name=gpt2
```

Answer (score 1):

In newer version of **transformer** you don't need to provide `model_name_or_path` anymore [check out here](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/no-skipping-steps-after-loading-from-checkpoint/6880/4). for this you should remove `--overwrite_output_dir` and `--model_name_or_path` then the last checkpoint in the `output_dir` would be loaded and the training continues from that checkpoint.

NOTE1:you should give `--tokenizer_name` because in this way you haven't provide `model_name_or_path` so the trainer doesn't know how to load tokenizer.

NOTE2: put `num_train_epochs` as big as meaningful for you because as long as you can `re-train` with the same command from the last checkpoint no need to define `--num_train_epochs=1` and no need to know what checkpoint the process is, like `checkpoint-5000` here.

So you can ruin this command instead:

```
!python3 run_clm.py \
--train_file source.txt \
--do_train \
--output_dir gpt-finetuned \
--per_device_train_batch_size 2 \
--save_steps 100 \
--num_train_epochs=10 \
--block_size=200 \
--tokenizer_name=gpt2
```